# Spring Java config exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to switch from xml config to java config and getting the following exception when starting the application.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy188 cannot be cast to org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService

This exception is thrown on the first line of the following method:

```
    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);

        return adapter;
    }
```

Any idea why this is failing?

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? Are all the dependencies that you are using the right versions that are necessary for your version of Spring? This might be a problem of mixing incompatible versions of libraries.

Comment: I am using the latest versions. Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE